# Открыть доступ только к определенному ресурсу iptables

Tags: iptables

Есть шлюз для выхода в интернет (192.168.0.1 eth1), есть сеть 192.168.0.0/24 с доступом в Интернет

```
#Разрешаем всем доступ в Интернет
sudo iptables -v -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```

в определенное время (в 14:00) я блокирую всем доступ в Интернет, кроме определенных пользователей:

```
#очищаем все правила iptables
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -X
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -t mangle -X
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -F POSTROUTING
#разрешаем 10-11-12 
sudo iptables -v -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.10/32 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -v -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.11/32 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -v -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.12/32 -j MASQUERADE
```

у определенных выше адресов 192.168.0.**10/11/12 итд** работает весь Интернет, а у остальных заблокированных ничего. Как открыть доступ только к определенному ресурсу (**rambler.ru**), остальным пользователям у которых заблокирован интернет? Пробовал делать так:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -d rambler.ru  -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -d rambler.ru  -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -d rambler.ru  -j ACCEPT
```

**Вывод iptables -L -n -v:**

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 19 packets, 1675 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            81.19.82.8
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            81.19.82.9
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            81.19.82.10
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            81.19.82.11

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 220 packets, 121K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    9   512 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       192.168.0.0/24       10.0.0.0/8
    6   246 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       10.0.0.0/8           192.168.0.0/24
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            81.19.82.9
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            81.19.82.10
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            81.19.82.11
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            81.19.82.8

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 18 packets, 2340 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            81.19.82.8
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            81.19.82.9
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            81.19.82.10
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            81.19.82.11
```

**Вывод iptables -nvL -t nat**:

```
root@gate:~# iptables -nvL -t nat
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 1706 packets, 197K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 211 packets, 20402 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 180 packets, 10525 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 589 packets, 39909 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    8   416 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      *       192.168.0.11        0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      *       192.168.0.12         0.0.0.0/0
    6   312 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      *       192.168.0.13         0.0.0.0/0
```

Тем не менее у заблокированных клиентов нет доступа к этому ресурсу.

Comment: `sudo iptables -v -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/24 -d 81.19.82.8 -j MASQUERADE` так? И указать все адреса рамблера. Но лично я бы использовал для этого `ipset`

Comment: Спасибо! Работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для "отчётности":
Простой способ в Вашем случае:

```
sudo iptables -v -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/24 -d 81.19.82.8 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -v -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/24 -d 81.19.82.9 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -v -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/24 -d 81.19.82.10 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -v -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/24 -d 81.19.82.11 -j MASQUERADE
```

Или создать новую табличку:

```
:ALLOW2NET - DROP [0:0]

-A ALLOW2NET -d 81.19.82.9 -j MASQUERADE
-A ALLOW2NET -d 81.19.82.8 -j MASQUERADE
-A ALLOW2NET -d 81.19.82.11 -j MASQUERADE
-A ALLOW2NET -d 81.19.82.10 -j MASQUERADE
```

И написать правило
`-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/24 -j ALLOW2NET`

Либо с помощью модуля `ipset`

Сначала установить ipset;

Создать сет
`create allow2net hash:net`

Добавить туда адреса

```
ipset add allow2net 81.19.82.9/32
ipset add allow2net 81.19.82.8/32
ipset add allow2net 81.19.82.10/32
ipset add allow2net 81.19.82.11/32
```

Написать правило
`-A PREROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/24 -m set --match-set allow2net dst -j MASQUERADE`

Последние 2 варианта предполагают, что у Вас есть файл с сохранёнными правилами iptables которые подгружаются при загрузке машины. Для варианта с ipset нужен так же ядерный модуль `xt_set (ipt_set)` .